# Tokenize a string in c++ without boost

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, tokenize

In this program, I am attempting to read in a line from a file, and tokenize the line and store the values into an array. I have created a struct called "Course" which stores information about courses that I read in from the file, and has an array storing the number of courses that depend on this particular course as a prerequisite. I am having difficulty tokenizing the line and storing it into the "dependencies" array.

The file I am trying to read in with tokenizing looks like this

```
2    6    
7    8    9    11    15
etc...
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std; 

typedef struct Course
{
    int numDependencies;
    int numPrerequisites;
    string name;
    //stores number of courses this course depends on
    int dependencies[6];
} Course;

int main()
{

int N;  //Number of courses
ifstream infile("CSCCourses.txt");
if (infile.fail()){
    cout << "File not found." << endl;
    //exit(0);
}
//read in number of courses
infile >> N;
//dynamically allocate array of courses
Course* courseArray = new Course[N];
string line;
//loop N times to read course names
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    infile >> line;
    cout << line << endl;
    courseArray[i].name = line;
}
//loop again to read course information
for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
    //Course dependencies[6];
    getline(infile,line);
    cout << line << endl;
    string::size_type lastPos = line.find_first_of(" ", 0);
    string::size_type pos = line.find_first_of(" ", lastPos);
    while (string::npos != pos || string::npos != lastPos) {
        //found token, add to array. 
        dependencies[].push_back(line.substr(lastPos, pos - lastPos));
        //skip delimiters
        lastPos = line.find_first_not_of(" ", pos);
        //find next non delimiter
        pos = line.find_first_of(" ", lastPos);
    }
}

infile.close();
```

}

Comment: Check [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream)

Comment: Look here for some ideas: [How do I tokenize a string in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c?rq=1)